# i did not resize the images

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-d130693892a2> in <module>

      7     image_path =  images_path + key

      8     image_array = cv2.imread(image_path)

----> 9     image_array = imresize(image_array, (48, 48))

     10     num_image_channels = len(image_array.shape)
     11 

               NameError: name 'imresize' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing cv2 with

```
import cv2
```

then change

```
image_array = imresize(image_array, (48,48))
```

to

```
image_array = cv2.resize(image_array, (48,48))
```

Comment: 4 xtrain = np.array(x_train) / 255
----> 5 xvalid = np.array(x_valid) / 255
      6 
      7 #Reshape the input features(x_train)

NameError: name 'x_valid' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
image_array = cv2.resize(image_array, (48, 48))
```

Because resize is a function of cv2